# Cannot transfer large file(s) using remote desktop connection (Windows 2012 server)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, ftp, remote-desktop, file-transfer

I am trying to transfer over a large file using remote desktop. I end up getting this error from the image below. Source computer is a windows 7 laptop and destination is a windows 2012R2 server.

Note: I was able to send small files over but when it comes to the larger files, I get this error or the RDP disconnects. Any clue? (Error: 0x800703E3)

- I have checked my RAM usage and the percentage is pretty low.
- I also checked disk storage and have alot of space where the files being transferred should not be an issue.

Error message is:

> An unexpected error is keeping you from copying the folder. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem.
>
> Error 0x800703e3: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
>
> file.zip
>   Type: Compressesd (zipped) Folder
>   Size: 1.09 GB
>   Date Modified: 2/1/2018 4:11 PM
>
> Try Again, Skip, Cancel

[Error window image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8qKF.png)

Comment: `I am trying to transfer over a large file using remote desktop with ftp` - That makes no sense. You're either transferring it via RDP or via FTP, but not both.

Comment: @joeqwerty I re-edited my question. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by transferring the files using the command xcopy from the power shell. Ultimately, I think moving files over with a shared drive resolve the issue.

```
xcopy [source path] [destination path]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this - killing the rdpclip process on the remote machine usually helps. Credits go to [Rony-L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16418/rony-l) and his reply [over here](https://serverfault.com/questions/194386/cant-copy-paste-between-my-desktop-a-remote-desktop)

Comment: Just in case anybody else reads this. It was similar but not quite the same. For some reason I had 2 rdpclip processes running. I killed one of them and tried the copy/paste method between the RDP window and locally and it worked then having previously failed by both the copy/paste and drag/drop between connected drive methods.